# Android OpenGL Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm getting this error

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0xa4b7b000 in tid 10818 (GLThread 54114)
```

When my app starts up. I'm testing rendering lots of points. It's crashing with 10,000 points and worked fine with 3,000.

```
public class PointRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    private int size = 10000;
    private FloatBuffer floatBuffer;

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        floatBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4*2*size).asFloatBuffer();

        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2*size; i++) {
            floatBuffer.put(r.nextFloat()*100);
        }
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int w, int h) {
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glPushMatrix();
            gl.glColor4f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
            gl.glVertexPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, floatBuffer);
            gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_POINTS, 0, size);
            gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glPopMatrix();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you have to rewind the buffer after filling it with data? That would be a problem at all sizes, though, so I figure that's either happening elsewhere in the code, or it's not needed for some reason.

Comment: Indeed I do. Weird that it worked with 3,000 without rewinding.